# How to set Github username in CocoaPods for pod lib create

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods

When creating a Cocoapod lib it uses my name `Mirko Kiefer` instead of github username `mirkokiefer` to generate the Podfile and Readme.

Answer (score 0):

Found this related Github issue: https://github.com/CocoaPods/pod-template/issues/126.

On macOS logging into Github on Safari will solve the issue as Cocoapods takes the username from the keychain.